# Progressbar.js setText dynamically

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I am trying to update the text inside a ProgressBar chart with specific text when I call a function.

JS:

```
var progressBarChart;

function progressBar(progressValue, textValue){
    if (progressBarChart == null) {
        progressBarChart = new ProgressBar.Circle (progress_container, {
            color: '#aaa',
            strokeWidth: 4,
            trailWidth: 1,
            easing: 'easeInOut',
            duration: 1400,
            text: {
                autoStyleContainer: false
            },
            from: {color: '#aaa', width: 1},
            to: {color: '#333', width: 4},
            step: function (state, circle) {
                circle.path.setAttribute ('stroke', state.color);
                circle.path.setAttribute ('stroke-width', state.width);
                circle.setText (textValue)

            }
        });
        progressBarChart.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
        progressBarChart.text.style.fontSize = '2rem';
    }
    progressBarChart.setText (textValue);
    progressBarChart.animate(progressValue);
}
```

And I call the function like this - eg when user provides some input

```
progressBar(progressValue, textToDisplay);
```

The chart animates as I repeatedly call the function but the text does not update. Any ideas how I can set text to a specific value as needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display a numerical value (eg count to 10 instead of 100) you can just pass in the value you want to count to:

```
function progressBar(progressValue, totalValue){
    if (progressBarChart == null) {
        progressBarChart = new ProgressBar.Circle (progress_container, {
            color: '#aaa',
            strokeWidth: 4,
            trailWidth: 1,
            easing: 'easeInOut',
            duration: 1400,
            text: {
                autoStyleContainer: false
            },
            from: {color: '#aaa', width: 1},
            to: {color: '#333', width: 4},
            step: function (state, circle) {
                circle.path.setAttribute ('stroke', state.color);
                circle.path.setAttribute ('stroke-width', state.width);
                var value = Math.round(circle.value() * totalValue);
                if (value === 0) {
                    circle.setText('');
                } else {
                    circle.setText(value);
                }
            }
        });
        progressBarChart.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
        progressBarChart.text.style.fontSize = '2rem';
    }
    progressBarChart.animate(progressValue);
}
```